# Server name for the database can not be accepted

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to connect to my database using `sql` in asp.net, but i could not. It shows me that there is an error on server name, because of the slash on the server name in the below code, but this is my actual server name.
How can i solve this problem? I'm using C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=ALLOOLATY\JASMINE;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=toys;");
try
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT name, id FROM product1", conn);
    SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        employeesLabel.Text += reader["name"] + "<br />";
    }    
    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: Use '\\' and Integrated Security=True in your connection string.

Comment: Never hardcode the connection string like that. Use an `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` to get a valid connection string.

Comment: Also put the connecting string in a config file and secure it if you required.

Answer (score 2):

The backslash character `\` is a special character that you need to escape like `\\` if you want to use it literally in a string:

```
"Server=ALLOOLATY\\JASMINE;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=toys;"
```

or you can make the whole string literal by prefixing it with `@`:

```
@"Server=ALLOOLATY\JASMINE;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=toys;"
```

Also, that doesn't look like a valid connection string.  Try this:

```
@"Data Source=ALLOOLATY\JASMINE;Initial Catalog=toys;Integrated Security=True"
```

Comment: it still shows the same error becuase of the slash \ between ALLOOLATY and / JASMINE

Answer (score 1):

Do not store connection strings in code. Moving the DB server will require a code update and deployment. Store connection strings in web.config. See [How to: Read Connection Strings from the Web.config File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx). I also encourage routing the configured connection string through a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` for cleaning.

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder scsb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(
     connectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"]);   
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(scsb.ConnectionString);
   {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT name, id FROM product1", conn))
        {
           using (SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
           {
              while (reader.Read())
              {
                     ...
              }
           }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use double slash in the place of single slash in server name :

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=ALLOOLATY\\JASMINE;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=toys;");
```

Comment: Why did you add that big space between "Integrated" and "Security"?